# Get access token request failed with OAuth::Unauthorized 401 problem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

First of all, I am trying to connect my app with an site in China. I am not sure if that matters, it shouldn't since that site fully supports Oauth.

Here is my code.

First step:

```
  require 'oauth'


   def consumer
     OAuth::Consumer.new("206506xxxx", "574705f63783xxxaa4a0bd35e34390fb", :site =>"http://api.t.sina.com.cn")
    end


 def request_token

    @request_token = consumer.get_request_token
  session[:request_token] = @request_token
    session[:request_token_secret] = @request_token.secret
 redirect_to @request_token.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => 'http://localhost:3000/accesstoken')

 end
```

It worked well, I was able to go to authorize_url and get an oauth_verifier

However, I encountered an issue when I was trying to get the access token.

```
 def access_token
 request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.new(
  consumer,
  session[:request_token],
  session[:request_token_secret]
)


access_token = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier=>params["oauth_verifier"])


 end
```

I also tried

```
   access_token = request_token.get_access_token
```

But they both returned 401 error.

I cleaned the session so it's probably not due to session expiry

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -3):

I solved the problem myself, so instead of using

```
  session[:request_token] = @request_token
```

I used

```
   session[:request_token] = @request_token.token
```

which worked.

Comment: What did you do to make this work? The solution you described is dull. request_token.token is a string and thus cannot used to get access_token if it's what you mean.